# Web.config authorization issue using Active Directory groups that contain additional subgroups

Tags: c#, .net, iis, active-directory, web-config

When you use the following code in your `web.config`, is there a way to allow for authorization of individuals who might be within subgroups of the listed AD role?

```
<location path="Restricted.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="FOOMAIN\AccessGroup" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

The AD groups are setup as such:

- **AccessGroup**

  - Subgroup1
  - Subgroup2
  - John.Foo
  - Jane.Bar
- **Subgroup1**

  - Billy.Jean
  - *Other.Individuals*

Currently, when *Billy.Jean* tries to access `Restricted.aspx`, they are rejected.

We'd love to be able to use **AccessGroup** in the `web.config` and be able to add subgroups for future access instead of having to make `web.config` or code changes. The possibility of just doing the authorization on `PageLoad` has been proposed but the business prefers to have these things set in configuration. The application is currently using Windows authentication and denies anonymous access site-wide.

Any ideas? Is there something I'm missing with how IIS performs this lookup? Is there a setting within AD that needs to be changed for the **AccessGroup**? <sub>I have no access to the IIS or AD settings and their respective admins are less than helpful.</sub>

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to finally sort this all out. The reason that **Subgroup1** and **Subgroup2** were not being accessed was because they are distribution groups and not security groups. When a respective security group is added that contains Billy.Jean, everything works properly. Basic answer to an infuriating problem.